# Secure Way To Use Parsley.js Validation in Form

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am using [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) for validation purpose of form. It works well for me as following.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" data-parsley-required-message="Enter First Name" required/>
```

Now, I think it is not secure for form validation. As anyone can go through InspectElement from the browser and remove the `required` attribute From Inspect.

So can I use parsley.js with jQuery or JavaScript for field validation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "secure" your form. A hacker could directly post anything to your server. You *absolutely* have to do the validations server side too, no way around it.

The reason we do validations client side is to provide a good user experience, not for security purposes.

Comment: Ok.. Hacker Can do anything.. But For a normal person who has knowledge of basic html, jquery can easily remove validation. So for normal person is there any best way to do validation at client size. means Without html attribute..